How can I limit the scopes to only the current spreadsheet and use OAuth to print a PDF
So I have this PDF Template hosted on a sheet.
I want to download it to my PC whenever a function is called.
I would like to limit it to only this spreadsheet.
I have the following appscript.json:
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/London",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": []
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}

(I need all of them for the other functions).
This is the code I use to download the PDF:
function downloadPDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
    id = ss.getId(),
    sht = ss.getSheetByName("PDF TEMPLATE"),
    shtId = sht.getSheetId(),

    url_base = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
    Logger.log(url_base)
    url =
      url_base +
      id +
      '/export' +
      '?format=pdf&gid=' +
      shtId;
      Logger.log(url)

    var val = 'Habits Checklist';
    val += '.pdf';

    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
    });
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(
      HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
        '<a target ="_blank" download="' +
          val +
          '" href = "data:application/pdf;base64,' +
          Utilities.base64Encode(res.getContent()) +
          '">Click here</a> to download, if download did not start automatically' +
          '<script> \
          var a = document.querySelector("a"); \
          a.addEventListener("click",()=>{setTimeout(google.script.host.close,10)}); \
          a.click(); \
          </script>'
      ).setHeight(50),
      'Downloading PDF..'
    );
    Logger.log('data:application/pdf;base64,' +
          Utilities.base64Encode(res.getContent()))
}

The script works great if I allow the full spreadsheets scope. However that wants edit access to all my spreadsheets. I would like to only limit it to the current file.
The error I get is linked to OAuthToken, and it is this:

Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 404. Truncated server response: <meta name="viewport" c... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

If I allow the full spreadsheets scope, it works without a problem.
Any feedback on this?
PS: This is the link to the file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IL1ztJYlHn1rYJirWbCq4l2seEemSp2e1s3bKarPqT0/edit?gid=0#gid=0
EDIT: It works if the file is shared with free access to it. If you remove share it stops working. Any ideas ?

Just add muteHttpExceptions: true to the second parameter of UrlFetchApp.fetch

Very interesting that your answer FIXES the problem yet it stops my pdf from having any content.
So it fixes the error but it kills the functionality.
Any idea why ?

This happens because the code does not evaluate the response received from UrlFetchApp. It's better not to assume that UrlFetchApp.fetch will always return, in this case, the PDF.

I'm sorry, I do not follow. So there is a chance it will return the PDF or did I understand it wrong ? I have tried it multiple times with the same result.

I made a copy of your spreadsheet. The generated PDF can't be opened, so before continuing to talk about the PDF, please ensure the PDF is generated correctly.

Yes, but if you try to remove the scope limitation it works !
So if the scope goes from
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly
to
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
it works

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

It works if the file is shared with free access to it.  That is to be expected. At that point, you probably don't need any scopes at all. I think it's probably important to note that /export endpoint belongs to Google drive api and might not work with spreadsheets.currentonly only(drive.file is another scope worth considering, but you'd need Google picker or the sheet needs to be created with this script for that scope to work).

This answer includes two examples. The first uses only one .gs file, and the second uses two files, one .gs and one .html.

The below code exports a specific sheet as a PDF without using UrlFetch. It uses a dialog with HTML and JavaScript that automatically closes after a few seconds.
Generally, it does the same as the code shown in the question but requires fewer authorization scopes. The major caveat is that the export URL, as far as I know, doesn't have a parameter to set the file name. If setting a specific file name is not critical, this might work as a workaround.
From the project information tab



Project OAuth Scopes
2 Scopes Requested




Display and run third-party web content in prompts and sidebars inside Google applications
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui


View and manage spreadsheets that this application has been installed in
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly



It was tested using a Google Workspace account with Advanced Security on a Mac with Sonoma 4.5 (23F79) and Chrome Versión 126.0.6478.127 (Build official) (arm64)
To run it on your side

Create a new spreadsheet
Insert a new sheet and set its name to Sheet to Export.
Add some content to the new sheet.
Click Extensions > Apps Script
On the Code.gs remove the default content and add the following code

/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

const SHEET_NAME =  'Sheet to Export';

/**
 * Downloads the specified sheet as a PDF.
 */
function downloadAsPDF() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME); 
  const sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  const spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId();

  const url_base = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/';
  const exportUrl = url_base + spreadsheetId + '/export?format=pdf&gid=' + sheetId; 
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput(`<a href="${exportUrl}" target="_blank">Open PDF</a>`)
    .append('<script>const link = document.querySelector("a");')
    .append('link.click();')
    .append('setTimeout(() => link.remove(), 100);')
    .append('setTimeout(() => google.script.host.close(), 2000);')
    .append('</script>'),
    "Download PDF"
  );
}


On the Google Apps Script Editor toolbar, click Run. You will be required to authorize the script. Authorize it.
Go back to the spreadsheet. Depending on your web browser settings, there might be an indicator that a popup was blocked. Click the indicator and click the link to execute the download. If the popup was not blocked, the sheet might be exported to the default download location or asked to set the download destination.


Below, there is another option. This time instead of HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(), HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile() is used. The default file name for the downloaded file is set using client-side code.
The project uses the same OAuth scopes as the previous example.
Code.gs
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

/** 
 * Included to add the required scope to the project manifest 
 * without having to edit it manually.
 */
// SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

/** type {string} Name of the sheet to be exported as PDF. */
const SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet to Export';
/** type {string} Do not include the file extension. */
const FILE_NAME = 'Exported Sheet';


/**
 * Downloads the specified sheet as a PDF.
 */
function downloadAsPDFAlt() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile('downloadAsPDF').evaluate().setHeight(100),
    "Download PDF"
  );
}

downloadAsPDF.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <p> Please wait </p>
  <script>
    <? const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); ?>
    <? const spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId(); ?>
    const sheetId = "<?!= spreadsheet.getSheetByName( SHEET_NAME ).getSheetId(); ?>";
    const fileName = "<?!= FILE_NAME ?>";
    const token = "<?!= ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() ?>";

    async function downloadSheetAsPDF(spreadsheetId, sheetId, fileName, token) {
      // 1. Construct the PDF export URL (same as before)
      const url = "<?= `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${spreadsheetId}/export?` ?>";
      const exportOptions = {
        format: "pdf",
        gid: sheetId 
      };

      const params = Object.keys(exportOptions)
        .map((key) => `${key}=${exportOptions[key]}`)
        .join("&");

      // 2. Use fetch to retrieve the PDF
      const response = await fetch(url + params, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, // Replace with your Google OAuth token
        },
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Error fetching PDF: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
      }

      // 3. Convert response to blob and create a download link
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    // 4. Create a temporary link and trigger download
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = downloadUrl;
    link.download = `${fileName}.pdf`;
    link.click();

    // 5. Clean up (revoke the temporary URL)
    URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);

    // 6. Close the dialog
    setTimeout (() => google.script.host.close(), 2000)
  }
  downloadSheetAsPDF("<?!= spreadsheetId ?>", sheetId, fileName, token);
  </script>
</body>

</html>

Related

Change the file name for google spreadsheet when downloaded as TSV
Can I specify the downloaded filename from the export URL?
GAS fileName parameter when export as csv

